# Is あれ？ when used like "huh/what?" contracted from something?

Tags: tag-question

I frequently hear 「あれ？」 when people find something that catches their attention, often even when a listening party is not present.  It seems to have a similar function to "what?", "what's that?", or "huh?".

Since あれ isn't a "question word" itself, was this あれ contracted from a longer sentence?  The closest I could think of is 「あれはなんだ？」, but I'm unsure.  If it isn't from a longer sentence, is there an explanation behind あれ as a question?

I am also interested in if it was historically contracted from something.

Comment: What is "what?!?!" contracted from in English? Why do you think using "that?!?!" makes any less sense than "what?!?!"? Both seem to make zero logical sense; they are simply idiomatic expressions.

Comment: I don't think I ever think of 「あれはなんだ？」 when I say あれ；in fact, あれ  rarely, if ever, even means "What is that?".

Comment: Unlike what you seem to think, we say あれ or あら to ourselves much more often than to others.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that this あれ is *not* the same word as in これ・それ・あれ? I could be crazy, but it seems like the former is あれ【LH】 and the latter is あれ【HL】.

Comment: @rintaun The pitch is certainly different (due to it being a question, albeit rhetorical). Whether it's "a different word" is more of a philosophical question I think. It definitely has a different meaning.

Comment: @rintaun I pronounce both as aré.

Comment: 「あら」とか関係あるんですか？

Comment: @rintaun In fact the pronoun is accentless, i.e. あれ【LH】, at least in the standard language. Perhaps you're thinking of the Kyoto accent, where it is indeed あれ【HL】.

Comment: Aside: how did you type the pitch accent?

Comment: @user54609 http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/982/1478

Comment: ありがとうございました!!!!

Comment: @nkjt http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8C?dic=daijisen&oid=00595300

Answer (score 5):

I think it's less a question than it is a way to show surprise or confusion.  Also I don't think it's contracted from anything, [this dictionary](http://www.japandict.com/lists/int) defines it as a [感動詞]{かんどうし} or interjection which would hint that it's not a contraction of a larger sentence.